# Python 3 pyplot.hold is deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to use the `pyplot.hold(True)` since I want to draw a contour plot on a scatter plot. When I use the below code, it has the warning that **pyplot.hold is deprecated**. Is there any other option in Python 3 or I just ignore the warning? Thank you very much.

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=150, c='b', 
marker='x', linewidths=1)
plt.hold(True)
plt.contour(X1, X2, Z, np.power(10,(np.arange(-20, 
0.1, 3)).T))
plt.hold(False)
```

Comment: You haven't described, why you want to add `plt.hold()` to your code. What do you want to achieve by it? The behaviour after the depreciation is like `plt.hold(True)`, meaning the current axes are not cleared on the next plot command.

Comment: Setting or unsetting hold (deprecated in version 2.1) has now been completely removed. Matplotlib now always behaves as if hold=True. To clear an axes you can manually use cla(), or to clear an entire figure use clf(). https://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html?highlight=pyplot%20hold

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib does not erase any content from a figure by itself. The concept of hold is hence not necessary in matplotlib and will be removed.

Your code should therefore look like

```
plt.scatter(..)
plt.contour(..)
```

Possibly followed by `plt.savefig(..)` or `plt.show()`.